# how to set font style to Constantia in tex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texstudio

I am using 'book' documentclass in tex (using texstudio over windows10) and would like to set the font-style to "Constantia" (as available in microsoft word). Can anyone please let me know how can I set this font-style and also how to check all the font-styles available in tex.

Comment: You can use it with `fontspec and `xelatex` or `luatalex`. However if you have maths to type, you'll have to find a maths font which goes well with this font.

Comment: Are you able to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX?

Comment: Yes, i changed the compiler to `xelatex` in tex-studio options. But still not able to set the font-style. For e.g. i tried using `\setmainfont{constantia}` but this gives error `Package fontspec Error: The font "constantia" cannot be found.` . How can i know which all font-styles are available ? Can i get a list of all supported font styles ? And if constantia is available how is it named in fontspec pkg.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\setmainfont{constantia}` with `\setmainfont{Constantia}`, i.e., if you capitalize the first letter?

Comment: @Mico : thanks, that worked :) . Can you also let me know how to get all the available font-styles available in fontspec pkg ? Also is it possible to set the font-size just like in microsoft word.

Comment: @mezda - I'm not sure I understand your follow-up  question. Specifically, what do you mean by "all available font-styles in the fontspec package"? Are you asking about which fonts are available? If so, the available fonts are *not* determined by `fontspec` at all. `fontspec` merely provides a straightforward method for accessing fonts that have already been installed.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the clarification. Yes i wanted to know which all font-styles are available just like we can see them all like a drop-down list in microsoft word.