# how to skip first page while using fancyhdr package in tex

Tags: fancyhdr

I am writing a tex document using book document class, and all the text is under `\begin{enumerate}`. I am also using fancyhdr pkg as follows :

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{book-title}
```

This is resulting in the book title getting printed in the header of every page, including the first page. But I want to skip putting the book-title on page header of first page and rather put the book-title in bold and bigger fonts on the first page. Is it possible to specify that as part of `\fancyhead` somehow, OR what is the way to achieve that ?

Comment: Have you tried issuing the directives `\thispagestyle{empty}` or `\thispagestyle{plain}` on the first page? The two page styles are very similar, except for the fact that the `empty` page style doesn't print a page number.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your answer. Using `\thispagestyle{empty}` removes the book-title from first page header, but it also removes the page-number from the bottom of the page as you told. Using `\thispagestyle{plain}` results in the desired result. Thanks a lot. Can you please provide the answer so that i can accept the same.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks Mico. I have one more question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499133/how-to-set-font-style-to-constantia-in-tex  . If you have any idea on the same, can you please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two main options:

- `\thispagestyle{plain}` -- With this instruction, the page number will be printed in the middle of the page footer; and
- `\thispagestyle{empty}` -- Very similar to `\thispagestyle{plain}`, except for the fact that the `empty` page style doesn't print a page number. (Put differently, nothing is written to either the header line or the footer line.)

Answer (score 1):

So, in the absence of a example, I guess that you are using some like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{book-title}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
{\Large\hfil book-title}
\begin{enumerate}\item foo \item etc. \end{enumerate}\newpage
\begin{enumerate}\item foo \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

While `\thispagestyle`can fix this mess as Mico showed, that is not really needed if you use the appropriate way of make titles, where the headers are automatically omitted. Seem  that you want the title in the first page of contents and not in a cover page (as usual in real books) so `book` is not the appropriate document class here.

In other word: use `\maketitle` and the `article` class instead of `book`, and you and you will not need make manual exceptions to the fancy header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{book-title}\author{}\date{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{book-title}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}\item foo \item etc. \end{enumerate}\newpage
\begin{enumerate}\item foo \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Or even without a real title, if you do not mind for some other changes of style in the document, some article-like  clasess, as `amsart` or `acmart` take care of not include the header in the first page:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{book-title}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section*{book-title}
\begin{enumerate}\item foo \item etc. \end{enumerate}\newpage
\begin{enumerate}\item foo \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```